# How to query a php page and save the value it returns to me?

Tags: swift

The purpose of the application built in Swift is to read a value, send it to a php page that returns a value corresponding to a url. Subsequently this url will be set in the webView to be displayed.

Currently my application sends the value and I can get the url in string format. My problem is that if I use that variable outside the URLSession.shared.dataTask process the variable is empty.

Searching the internet I discovered that the reason is that the operation is performed in another thread, so how can I maintain the persistence of that value?

I'm developing in swift 4.2

```
func risolutoreIndirizzo() -> String {
        var addressURL:String = ""

        let domain = "https://mywebsite.com/"
        let domain = "getUrl.php"
        print("URL -> \(domain+domain)")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: domain+domain)! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let nameDB = "SVILUPPO"
        let postString = "StringaAccesso=\(nameDB)"

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            //print("response = \(response)")
            let responseString:String! = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String?

            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            print("---------------------------------")

            let arrayResponse = responseString.split(separator: ",")
            //print(arrayResponse[0])
            addressURL = arrayResponse[0].split(separator: ":")[1] + ":" + arrayResponse[0].split(separator: ":")[2]

            print("AddressURL -> " + addressURL)//Here I see correctly -> https://mywebsite.com/privateProject 

            stringURl = addressURL //stringURl initialized at the beginning of the code



        }
        task.resume()

        print("URL -> " + stringURl)//Here the variable is empty

        return addressURL
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Closures:

```
func risolutoreIndirizzo(completion: @escaping (_ result: String) -> Void) {
    ...
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in
        ...
        completion(addressURL)
    }
    ...
}
```

Use:

```
risolutoreIndirizzo() { address in
    print(address)
}
```

[Apple Developer Documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, it works but now added the following code I have an error.


Code:
`let url = URL(string: address)!
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
            // 2
            let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self.webView, action: #selector(self.webView.reload))
            self.toolbarItems = [refresh]
            self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true`


Error:
`Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @Lorenzo97Ben The variable "address" looks empty. Check address value: print(address)

Comment: print(address) returns a string

Now my code is:

`risolutoreIndirizzo() { address in
            print("Address -> " + address)
            
            let url = URL(string: address)!
            self.webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
            // 2
            let refresh = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self.webView, action: #selector(self.webView.reload))
            self.toolbarItems = [refresh]
            self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
        }`

And the problem is a : let url = URL(string: address)!

Comment: print("Address -> " + address) => Address -> "https:\/\/www.mywebsite.com\/privateProject\/file.php"

Comment: Try address = address.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\/", with: "/") before let url = URL(string: address)!

Comment: I applied your code, the print changes but the error remains

print("Address -> " + address) => Address -> https://mywebsite.com/privateProject/file.php

Comment: There is but the editor modifies it

`print("Address -> " + address) => Address -> https://mywebsite.com/privateProject/file.php`

Comment: @Lorenzo97Ben Can you put this piece of code on GitHub to show the error? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: https://github.com/lorenzomalferrari/fileSwift/blob/master/ViewController.swift

Currently I have had to modify the strings with respect to the real url of our site. I hope, however, that I wrote it clearly and that you can help me

Comment: @Lorenzo97Ben I sent pull request on GitHub. There are my comments. I hope this will help solve the problem. https://github.com/lorenzomalferrari/fileSwift/pull/1/commits/f240feb59e5df0135b6394a343faa96c6dade983